# C# asynchronous socket, missing packet on server overload

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asyncsocket

I have written an asynchronous server using .Net socket, and when this server is overloaded (receiving a lot of data, file for example), all the packets are not received by the server.

If I increase the length of buffer, I receive more data but not all the packets.

Is anybody have a solution to my problem?

The code of my server is :

```
class ServerFile
{
    #region Delegate
    private delegate void Method(ConnectionInfoFile Infos, Object Content);
    #endregion
    #region Fields
    private Int32 Port;
    private Socket ServerSocket = null;
    private List<ConnectionInfoFile> Connections = new List<ConnectionInfoFile>();
    private Dictionary<Command, Method> Map = new Dictionary<Command, Method>();
    #endregion
    #region Constructor
    public ServerFile(Int32 Port)
    {
        this.Port = Port;
        this.Map[Command.Server_User_Login] = this.Login;
    }
    #endregion
    #region Methods - Login
    private void Login(ConnectionInfoFile Client, Object Content)
    {
        Client.Id = (Int32)Content;
        Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "] - " + this.GetType().Name.Insert(6, " ") + " - The client is now authentified as '" + Client.Id + "'.");
    }
    #endregion
    #region Methods - Receive
    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult Result)
    {

        ConnectionInfoFile Connection = (ConnectionInfoFile)Result.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            Int32 BytesRead = Connection.Socket.EndReceive(Result);
            if (BytesRead != 0)
            {
                Byte[] Message = (new MemoryStream(Connection.AsyncBuffer, 0, BytesRead)).ToArray();
                Connection.Append(Message);
                Packet Packet;
                while ((Packet = Connection.TryParseBuffer()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "] - " + this.GetType().Name.Insert(6, " ") + " - Command received : " + Packet.Command.ToString());
                    if (Packet.Recipient == 0)
                    {
                        if (this.Map.ContainsKey(Packet.Command))
                            this.Map[Packet.Command](Connection, Packet.Content);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (ConnectionInfoFile Item in this.Connections)
                        {
                            if (Item.Id == Packet.Recipient)
                            {
                                Byte[] Buffer = Packet.Serialize(Connection.Id, Packet.Command, Packet.Content);
                                this.Send(Item, Buffer);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Connection.Socket.BeginReceive(Connection.AsyncBuffer, 0, Connection.AsyncBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), Connection);
            }
            else
                this.CloseConnection(Connection);
        }
        catch (SocketException E)
        {
            CloseConnection(Connection);
            Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "] - " + this.GetType().Name.Insert(6, " ") + " - Receive socket exception : " + E.SocketErrorCode);
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            CloseConnection(Connection);
            Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "] - " + this.GetType().Name.Insert(6, " ") + " - Receive exception : "+ E.Message);
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region Methods - CloseConnection
    private void CloseConnection(ConnectionInfoFile Connection)
    {
        Connection.Socket.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "] - " + this.GetType().Name.Insert(6, " ") + " - The user " + Connection.Id + " has been disconnected !");
        lock (this.Connections)
        {
            this.Connections.Remove(Connection);
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region Methods - Send
    protected void Send(IConnectionInfo Connection, Byte[] Buffer)
    {
        Connection.Socket.BeginSend(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), Connection);
    }
    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult Result)
    {
        try
        {
            IConnectionInfo Connection = (IConnectionInfo)Result.AsyncState;
            Int32 BytesSent = Connection.Socket.EndSend(Result);
            Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "] - " + typeof(ServerFile).Name.Insert(6, " ") + " - Sent " + BytesSent + " bytes " + Connection.Id.ToString() + ".");
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "] - " + typeof(ServerFile).GetType().Name.Insert(6, " ") + " - Exception : " + E.ToString());
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region Methods - Stop
    public void Stop()
    {
        this.ServerSocket.Close();
        this.ServerSocket = null;
    }
    #endregion
    #region Methods - Start
    public void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "] - " + this.GetType().Name.Insert(6, " ") + " - Start listening on port " + this.Port + "...");
        this.ServerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        this.ServerSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, this.Port));
        this.ServerSocket.Listen((Int32)SocketOptionName.MaxConnections);
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            this.ServerSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(this.AcceptCallback), this.ServerSocket);
    }
    #endregion
    #region Methods - Accept
    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult Result)
    {
        ConnectionInfoFile Connection = new ConnectionInfoFile();
        Socket Socket = (Socket)Result.AsyncState;
        try
        {

            Connection.Socket = Socket.EndAccept(Result);
            Connection.ConnectionDate = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "] - " + this.GetType().Name.Insert(6, " ") + " - A new client has been registered");
            lock (this.Connections)
            {
                this.Connections.Add(Connection);
            }
            Connection.Socket.BeginReceive(Connection.AsyncBuffer, 0, Connection.AsyncBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), Connection);
        }
        catch (SocketException E)
        {
            this.CloseConnection(Connection);
            Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "] - " + this.GetType().Name.Insert(6, " ") + " - Accept socket exception: " + E.SocketErrorCode);
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            this.CloseConnection(Connection);
            Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "] - " + this.GetType().Name.Insert(6, " ") + " - Accept exception: " + E.Message);
        }
        Socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), Result.AsyncState);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Sorry for my English and thanks a lot.

NeoKript

Comment: Why don't you design your solution so that that server will scale (up to a resonable limit) when the requests are increasing?

Comment: What did you mean by 'scale' ? Grow up the length of the buffer when a lot of data is incoming ? I can't know that.

Comment: You can have a pool of worker threads that can process your requests. When a request comes in, it will get processed by a thread in that pool. After processing the request, the thread will be returned to the pool. So, you can process multiple requests. Of course, there are more patterns that this one.

Comment: So you advise me to not use async read and write, but read/write socket in a thread for each client ?

Comment: The definitive answer is "It depends". I would try some async read/write with some threading. But not a thread per client or a thread per request because, for a lot of clients or requests, that would starve your system. You could have a thread pool of 20-50 (or even adaptive number) of threads waiting. Why adaptive? You can first put 20 in there, then, when needed, add more, say 50, and so on. Then once in a while, if some threads stay in the pool too much, you can reduce the pool size. Still, this may be too complicated. It depends...

Comment: Could this just be problem with the NIC Buffer? The NIC will only accept so much data before it rejects it. Could this be due to the fact that you are not processing message faster enought that at the hardware/NIC level it runs out of memory and does not attempt to resend/timesout?